# Grant permissions like Linux

Tags: php, math

I grant permissions for persons like this:

```
$ARR_PERSON = array(
     2 => "Person B",
     4 => "Person C",
     8 => "Person D",
     16 => "Person E",
     32 => "Person F",
    );
```

The problem is I don't know how to get the permission when I have a number. For example: 24. How to split it into 8 and 16? I can't think out the solution.

Comment: how it is implemented? why not 4, 4, 4, 4.... or 16, 4, 4? or 2, 2, ..... or 2, 2, 4, ....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using bitwise operations. When `PERMISSION & MASK` is nonzero (e.g, `24 & 16`), the flag is set. When it is zero, the flag is not set.

Comment: I don't get it. Could you elaborate it? Which function should I use?

Comment: Loop through your permissions and test `($user->permissions & mask) != 0`? It's really not that complicated.

Comment: The number you're asking about. Surely you haven't forgotten your own question yet?

Comment: :D Oh got it. Have just tried it. Thank you.